# How can I compare the sum of one field to another single field?

Tags: mysql, sum, outer-join

My data set is like so:

- **Total_Order_Table**
- Order_no (unique)
- Shipped_quantity
- **Order_Detail_Table**
- Order_number (not unique)
- Quantity_per_bundle

I need to take the sum of Quantity_per_bundle for each order_number from Order_Detail_Table and compare it to the Shipped_quantity.

My idea is an outer join so that my data will look like so:

[image]

I need to be able to see quantity discrepancies and if the order number exists in both tables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do the sum (grouped by order#) in a subquery, then join that to the "total" table with a LEFT JOIN where the subquery is on the right of the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly with a FULL OUTER JOIN in sql:

```
SELECT to.Order_no AS Order_no_Total_Order_Table, od.Order_number AS Order_No_Ordr_detail_Table, SUM(od.Order_number) AS sum_Quanitty_Per_Bundle, od.Order_number 
FROM Total_Order_Table AS to
FULL OUTER JOIN Order_Detail_Table AS od ON  to.Order_no = od.Order_number
GROUP BY to.Order_no
```

But FULL OUTER JOIN don't exist in mysql. But you can simulate it : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something subtle in the question, isn't this just as simple as a `SELECT` query with a join between the tables.

Something along the lines of this should achieve the result:

```
SELECT  tot.Order_no,
        odt.Order_no,
        SUM(odt.Quantity_per_bundle),
        tot.Shipped_quantity
  FROM  Total_Order_Table tot
    LEFT JOIN Order_Detail_Table odt ON odt.Order_Number = tot.Order_Number
  GROUP BY tot.Order_no, odt.Order_no, tot.shipped_quantity
```

(Code not tested in MySQL so forgive errors)

Comment: This works great for just order quantity discrepancy, but it does not show me if one order exists in only one of the tables.